# Large dimension SVG image not showing in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, image, firefox, svg, mozilla

I am having an issue with **displaying large dimension SVG images in firefox**. In chrome the image shows without any problem, But in Mozilla Firefox the image is not showing.

**If I open that image  alone in a separate  tab the image displays, But not with html  page.**

png Image is working fine. Only SVG images having this issue.

I am attaching a sample code here

```css
.box {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background:#000;
}
.box img {
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/5/13/17fdee32fe17f99ecc798e99a0c945e4-full.png"/>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/D2d.svg"/>
</div>
```

[This is the codepen link](https://codepen.io/abdulhakkim/pen/QRKppz)

Can any one please help me with this?

Comment: https://svgshare.com/i/D2d.svg is not reachable. Perhaps you have it cached in Chrome from when the site was functional.

Comment: I have fixed this issue by using object method, instead of 'img' tag. Thank you.

Comment: I imagine you used external references which <img> does not allow. Without seeing the file it's hard to tell for sure.

Comment: Yeah... I know.. I used some external image CDN for snippet uses. However Firefox have some issues with the extreme large dimension SVG images. Thanks for your help.. :-)

Comment: Whatever issues in dimension Firefox has would not be affected by the choice of <img> vs <object> to display things. Your issue is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: But the same image worked when I used object, but not with img tag. My svg image havw 86520px width. Which is not rendering with img tag.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by using `object` tag instead of `img` tag. The code looks like this,

Object Name